# Import a column of data, make a sum on them

Tags: import

I import a data file, then do calculation on it and after that I want to sum on my output data. Here is my sample code:

```
For[i = 0, i < 6, {
a = Import["myfile.data", {"Words", i }] // ToExpression;
b=10+a;
Print[b];}, i++];
```

Sum[b]?

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Note that it is `For[start,test,incr,body]`. Also it would be helpful to see what structure your imported data is of. Are you shure, b is a flat list of numbers?

Comment: My imported data is a "DATA File (.data)".Yes "b" is a simple list of numbers. Thank's for your comment

Comment: If `b` is a list of numbers, then you can use `Total[b]`. If you are unsure what `b` is, try `FullForm[b]`.

Comment: I tried command Total[b], but it didn't work well. The out put was: "Total[Null]" or Total[the last calculated b]

Comment: `b` is not a list unless `a` is a list, which seems unlikely given your import statement.   Also `.data` is not a standard/meaningful file extension.  Show a few lines of the file so we don't have to guess what it means.

Comment: Dear george2079; "a" is a list (Energy of electron in GeV: 0.57, 0.73, 1.23,..). "b" is a list too (Flux of electron) which is obtained by doing calculation on "a" ! ".data" is a data file, contains experimental data and opens by Notepad. I have 6 data in my out put which refers to "b", but I want 1 put which should be the sum of  these 6 data.

Comment: I fail to see how `Import`-ing a single (`i`th)  "Word" results in a list.

Comment: Resulting a list is due to the "For loop" structure. At first, it imports the first word, after that imports the second one and etc. The result will be a set of data